Unable to exclude folder in tsconfig
I have a folder that is generated by OpenAPI Generator and has some unused variables in it. I would like to exclude this folder because I get many warnings about "unused variables" that prevents the build.
This is a typical vite project created with create-vite-app
However, I cannot get it to work!
tsconfig.json
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    { "path": "./tsconfig.app.json" },
    { "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
  "exclude": ["src/lib/api/**"]
}

tsconfig.app.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    // tailwinds + shadcn
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false, // change to true after fixing ignore src/lib/api TODO
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUncheckedSideEffectImports": true
  },
  "exclude": ["src/lib/api/**"]
}

tsconfig.node.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.node.tsbuildinfo",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "lib": ["ES2023"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "noEmit": true,

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUncheckedSideEffectImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"],
  "exclude": ["src/lib/api/**"]
}


here are my three tsconfig files, but no combination of exclude the src/lib/api/ folder prevents the errors from showing up when i run npm run build

i found that configuring excludes is the hardest part in TS :)

I found the solution after some googling and experimenting.
First i removed any additional information in the base config, then added the includes and excludes to the app.json and node.json files
Finally for good luck, i removed the node_modules/.tmp/ folder and ran tsc -b --clean so there was no previous caching
For example, i added this to both of the tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.node.json
 "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["src/lib/api/**/*", "src/lib/api"]

